# Bash prefix variable number of spaces to a line

Tags: bash, printf

I want to create text output in Bash that looks like this:

```
abc - Line 1
      Line 2
      Line 3
```

I am using the following code to try and do this but it is not working

```
var=¨abc¨
printf ¨%s - %s\n¨ var ¨Line 1¨
printf ¨%*s   %s\n¨ ${#var} ¨¨ ¨Line 2¨
printf ¨%*s   %s\n¨ ${#var} ¨¨ ¨Line 3¨
```

I get results that look like this:

```
    $ ./test1
    ¨-¨%s¨n¨¨¨¨abc¨¨¨¨Line¨1¨./test1: line 3: printf: %sn¨: invalid number
    ./test1: line 3: printf: ¨¨: invalid number
    ./test1: line 3: printf: 2¨: invalid number
    ¨5¨¨Line¨  ./test1: line 4: printf: %sn¨: invalid number
    ./test1: line 4: printf: ¨¨: invalid number
    ./test1: line 4: printf: 3¨: invalid number
    ¨5¨¨Line¨
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're using strange double quotes? `¨` instead of `"`.

Comment: That is what my computer generates. I am using a US International Keyboard.

Comment: I don't know how you can reconfigure that, but I can tell you that it confuses Bash.

Comment: You are writing umlauts and not double quotes. Maybe you are not holding down shift when you are pressing the key?

Comment: According to my reading of [this layout](https://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html), the correct key is directly to the left of the "Enter" key (and requires shift).

Comment: It shows as the double quote character on my keyboard.

Comment: once you figure out how to print (real) double quotes, the next issue will be addressing the 2nd/3rd `printf` calls ... both are expecting 3 args ... 1 numeric + 2 strings ... but each of these calls only has 2 args ... 1 numeric + 1 string

Comment: @Benjamin W That is the character that I am typing and I have been doing this for many years. I am using Ubuntu 20.10 and this keyboard relies on operating system support to go things right.

Comment: @Benjamin W So far as I can see these lines do have 3 arguments to printf, the length of the field - an empty field to use for initial line spacing and the text for the line.

Comment: @that other guy If I did not press the shift key I would get an apostrophe - ´

Comment: fwiw, I cut-n-paste the code snippet into Windows/notepad, set the font to really large and instead of double quotes I see 2 dots (ie, umlaut or diaeresis)

Comment: @fwiw In that case it may be a problem with Ubuntu. I have used this keyboard layout and these characters for many years without problems.

Comment: @Jonathan you have to provide a placeholder for the 'empty field' ... either `" "` or `""`  ... see kvantour's answer for an example

Comment: @Jonathan try a google search on `ubuntu international keyboard double quotes umlaut diaeresis` ... this provides several hits that sound/look familiar to your issue, eg, [this](https://superuser.com/q/518806)

Comment: @markp-fuso I believe that the problem may be that my keyboard does not have a Linux driver. I was running Windows 10 on this machine with the vendor´s driver without problems as well as Ubuntu using an earlier keyboard that gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is obviously the quoting problem. Double quotes are `"` and not `¨`. This is probably due to the usage of the keyboard "ENG INTL" or "US International". I recommend it to just put it on a simple "US" keyboard which gets rid of all diacritics. If you need diacritics, then implement a compose key.

For the rest, ignoring the wrong quotes, your solution is close to correct. The `%*s` still expects a string which you did not provide, so the solution is:

```
printf "%s - %s\n" "${var}" "Line1"
printf "%*s   %s\n" "${#var}" "" "Line2"
printf "%*s   %s\n" "${#var}" "" "Line3"
```

Comment: That is what I thought that I provided.

Comment: In your original question you did not add the empty string (`""`) which is passed to `%*s`

Comment: You are right. I corrected this but it seems that the quotes problem is getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is either a keyboard driver problem or a problem with the Ubuntu operating system. Changing my keyboard layout to English US made the problem disappear.